# What is the simplest way to get the length of a range or set of items in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, count, scripting

I have a situation where I might specify a for loop range using either

- a range
  "{1..10}"
  e.g. length = 10
- or a set of items
  "tcp udp"
  e.g. length = 2

What is the simplest way to get the length of that set?

Comment: Please add your desired output  for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: you may want to provide more details of the actual issue you're trying to solve including the actual data you're trying to parse/count; do you need to worry about embedded white space? what about control/non-printing characters? do you need to determine the number of times you execute a `while` loop while parsing this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, create an array:

```
$ x=({1..10})
$ y=(tcp udp)
```

then use parameter expansion to get the number of elements in the array.

```
$ echo "${#x[@]}"
10
$ echo "${#y[@]}"
2
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thanks! I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough points after 12 years, ha. Someday I'll be a real programmer #stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
# Bash, as brace expansion are not POSIX
count=0
for _ in {1..10}; do ((count++)); done
echo "$count" # 10

# POSIX compliant
count=0
for _ in tcp udp; do : $((count=count+1)); done
echo "$count" # 2
```

But neither of these things makes sense, as if you know the values beforehand then you would also know the count.

If you have an array in bash, then you can simply read the length:

```
arr=({1..10})
echo "${#arr[@]}" # 10

arr=(tcp udp)
echo "${#arr[@]}" # 2
```

Or if you have a file, or a list of matches from eg. `grep` then either using `wc -l` or `grep -c` would work:

```
$ my_cmd | wc -l
$ my_cmd | grep -c 'pattern'
```

Comment: Clarification, I don't know the values ahead of time, I was trying to simplify the example to get at the specific question I asked.

Comment: If you don't know values `1` and `10` aot but get them later `{n..m}` then `count = m - n`?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks
arr=({1..10})
echo "${#arr[@]}" # 10

arr=(tcp udp)
echo "${#arr[@]}" # 2

Comment: @hognala you are welcome